# I'm trying to run Xubuntu 64 on Oracle VMBox and I have an error that Intel Virtualization is not enabled despite the BIOS and stating otherwise

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, bios, thinkpad

I'm brand new to tech as a whole. I'm starting The Odin Project and trying to run Xubuntu on the Oracle VMBox. This error is showing:

[image: VMBox Error]

I used [Enabling Intel VT-x and AMD-V Virtualization Hardware Extensions in BIOS](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/sect-troubleshooting-enabling_intel_vt_x_and_amd_v_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_bios) from [RedHat's Virtualization Deployment and Administration Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/index) to enable Intel VT-x and went to my Thinkpad's BIOS to do this:

[image: Virtualization is enabled]

Sure enough, the task manager agrees:

[image: Task Manager]

However I'm still getting the error message above.

On RedHat's guide the part at the end might be my hang-up:

[image: Step 4]

Here's what happens when I try that:

[image: Command prompt]

[image: Command prompt as admin]

Comment: Welcome Unfortunately no one wNts to look taller 8 links, to help you. Please update it and put more relevant info such as error message and settings. Using images fir text info is not good.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You cannot use guides for Linux on Windows. // Do you have Hyper-V, Virtual Machine Platform and/or Windows Hypervisor Platform enabled? Or maybe Windows Defender Core Isolation?

Comment: If Hyper-V has been completely uninstalled, then uninstall Virtual Box, restart, install Virtual Box again and try to install Xbuntu 64 again. I have Ubuntu 64 running as a guest in VMware Workstation.

Comment: we need the hardware spec of the machine and model before anything else - most likely your bios needs an update or your processor may be not up to the task

Comment: Highly unlikely. All the relevant specs are in the Task Manager screenshot. // Also, just to be clear: VirtualBox can work with Hyper-V enabled. // What we need are the enabled Windows Features.